# Spring batch + repository Testing

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, spring-test

This is my reader that work in job and step i'u using a repository to get users(`public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long>`):

```
    @Slf4j
    public class Reader implements ItemReader<User> {
    
        @Autowired
        UserRepository userRepository;
    
        private Iterator<User>userIterator;
    
        @BeforeStep
        public void before(StepExecution execution){
            userIterator=userRepository.findAll().iterator();
        }
    
        @Override
        public User read() {
            if (userIterator != null && userIterator.hasNext()) {
                User user=userIterator.next();
                log.info("User-->"+user.toString());
                return user;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    
    }
```

This is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringBatchApplication.class, BatchTestConfiguration.class})
public class SpringBatchApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils testUtils;

    @Autowired
    private BatchConfig config;

    @Test
    public void testEntireJob() throws Exception {
        final JobExecution result = testUtils.getJobLauncher().run(config.processJob(), testUtils.getUniqueJobParameters());
        Assert.assertNotNull(result);
        Assert.assertEquals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED, result.getStatus());
    }


    @Test
    public void testSpecificStep() {
        Assert.assertEquals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED, testUtils.launchStep("orderStep1").getStatus());
    }

}
```

When i`m running my test i got a :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot determine embedded database for tests. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.
```

What do i need to add to make determine of my database. Do i need to place application properties somewhere or something else?

There is how my test situate in project [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L752Y.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot determine embedded database for tests. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41325154/cannot-determine-embedded-database-for-tests-if-you-want-an-embedded-database-p)

Comment: How do you want your test setup to look like? Use an embedded database or your actual database by [starting a Docker container with Testcontainers](https://rieckpil.de/howto-write-spring-boot-integration-tests-with-a-real-database/)?